# How to assert nested array with other expected array

Tags: javascript, arrays, assertion

How to easily assert nested array elements with another array values? I tried the following but it's not working as expected.

```
var expectedCells = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
var actual = [['a'], ['b', 'e'], ['e'], ['c']] //['b', 'e'] should also return true 
actual.forEach(element => console.log(expectedCells.includes(element))); 

//Expected: true, true, false, true but it returns false, false, false, false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array#some` to check if any of the array elements are in the other array.

```js
var expectedCells = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
var actual = [['a'], ['b', 'e'], ['e'], ['c']] //['b', 'e'] should also return true
actual.forEach(element => console.log(element.some(x => expectedCells.includes(x))));
```

Answer (score 0):

`expectedCells.includes(element)` checks, if a nested array of `actual` is in the `expectedCells` array, which only contains strings, so the output is always `false`

What you need to do is to also iterate over the elements of the nested array.

```
var expectedCells = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
var actual = [['a'], ['b', 'e'], ['e'], ['c']] //['b', 'e'] should also return true

actual.forEach(elements => {
    for (let i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        if (expectedCells.includes(elements[i])) {
            return console.log(true)
        }
        return console.log(false)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things going on here.

First, you aren't comparing the elements inside of `actual`'s subarrays. You're comparing the subarrays themselves.

`actual.forEach(...)` is executing something like this:

```js
console.log(expectedCells.includes(['a']))
console.log(expectedCells.includes(['b', 'e']))
console.log(expectedCells.includes(['e']))
console.log(expectedCells.includes(['c']))
```

None of the array objects will match the letters `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d` from the `expectedCells` array.

You'll have to create a double loop:

```js
actual.forEach(
  elementArray =>
    console.log(
      elementArray.some(element => expected.includes(element))
    )
  )
```